# Assigning strings to pointer in C

Tags: c, strings, pointers

My question is about pointers in C. As far as I've learned and searched, pointers can only store addresses of other variables, but cannot store the actual values (like integers or characters). But in the code below the char pointer c actually storing a string. It executes without errors and give the output as 'name'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
  char *c;
  c="name";
  puts(c);
}
```

Can anyone explain how a pointer is storing a string without any memory or if memory is created where it is created and how much size it can be created?

I tried using it with the integer type pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
  int *c;
  c=10;
  printf("%d",c);
}
```

but it gave an error

```
cc     test.c   -o test
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:5:3: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast   [enabled by default]
c=10;
^
test.c:6:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
printf("%d",c);
^
```

Pointers stores the address of variable then why is integer pointer different from character pointer?

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: It looks like you are using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Always use `gcc -Wall -g` to compile your code. Don't forget to get all warnings with `-Wall` and debugging information with `-g`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is just the way string literals work in C. String literals like `"name"` are arrays of characters, it is equivalent to the five element array `{'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', '\0'}`. For the code

```
char *c;
c="name";
```

the environment reserves memory for the above array already at initialization time, when the program is loaded from disk into memory. At run time, the adress of the beginning of that array is assigned to c.

Note the first piece of code of yours is not equivalent to the second, because in the first piece you assign a **string literal** (and not a character like 'n') to a `char*` variable. In the second, you try to assign an `int` (and not an `int array`) to an `int*`.

[Here is a tutorial on strings and pointers in C with a more detailed explanation](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/ch3x.htm).

Comment: I'm not sure that *initialization time* is the good word. I would say *compile time*. Program initialization is often the beginning of its execution.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Initially, I was considering to write "compile time", but then noted that this is not really correct. The compiler writes the characters into the binary file of your executable - but the memory to which `char*c` points is the memory where the operating system places that data when loading the file from disk.

Comment: But the initialization of that (virtual) memory chunk happened when the executable was produced -perhaps many months ago-, not when it runs.

Comment: I wrote about *virtual* memory (which is the memory relevant for application execution), and you speak of physical RAM. On Linux `execve` is sort-of `mmap`-ing the text segment of the ELF executable, and the literal string is a constant inside that text segument

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: you are intermixing virtual memory (which is memory the os provides for the execution) with the binary bytes of the executable.

Comment: the text segment is projected into virtual memory by the `execve` syscall. So when the program starts to run, its virtual memory is already set up to contain the text segment of the ELF executable of the program.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: you are talking about the point in time when the program was loaded from disk, immediately before it starts to run - but that is obviously not "compile time". Call it "load time", if you don't like the term "initialization time", but "compile time" does not fit.

Comment: No, I was talking about build (actually link) time. The virtual memory used by a process (just after `execve`) has a skeleton defined by the segments provided by the ELF executable, and these segments are defined at build time, not at run time. If you have built your executable ten years ago, the text segment is always the same, at the same virtual address (unless you have linked with the uncommon `-fPIE` flag for position independent executables.)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: the compiler (and static linker) may define a memory layout at compile (or link) time, but the reservation of the actual memory in use happens (probably 10 years) later. But you don't have to demonstrate that understanding, I believe you that you have understood the details - this is about a linguistic problem, I think "compile time" is just the wrong term for my answer. Maybe initialization time is not ideal, too, but IMHO still better.

Comment: No, I am talking of virtual memory but you are talking of physical RAM, which really is only used thru the virtual memory abstraction by application programs (so they only see virtual memory).

Answer (score 3):

String literals like `"name"` are stored as arrays of `char` (`const char` in C++) such that they are allocated when the program starts and held until the program terminates.

The *type* of the expression `"name"` is "5-element array of `char`" (5th element for the 0 terminator).  Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `*` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize an array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

So, when you write

```
c="name";
```

`"name"` is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `*` operators, and it isn't being used to initialize an array in a declaration, so the *address* of the first element of the string is being assigned to the pointer variable `c`.  Essentially, what you have in memory is something like the following:

```
            +-----+
"name"[0] : | 'n' |  <-------+
            +-----+          |
"name"[1] : | 'a' |          |
            +-----+          |
"name"[2] : | 'm' |          |
            +-----+          |
"name"[3] : | 'e' |          |
            +-----+          |
"name"[4] : |  0  |          |
            +-----+          |
              ...            |
            +-----+          |
        c : |     | ---------+
            +-----+
```